# Connecting headphones to TV to hear sound from PS3

Tags: hdmi, tv, headphones, ps3

I am seeking information regarding whether this is possible. Here is the current set-up:

- Sony TV (I will get info regarding model) connected to PS3 via HDMI.
- Sony TV has a headphone jack.

What I would like to do is to connect my headphones to the TV so I can hear the PS3 sound from the headphones. I know I can connect the headphones to PS3 directly but I want to control the sound levels through the TV remote.

I have tried connecting and changing the TV settings, however, heard nothing from the headphones. I haven't tried changing PS3 settings; I will later on.

I am curious whether this is at all possible; I heard before that a TV cannot do both input from HDMI and output -said input- at the same time.

Comment: I can confirm it is possible - did it myself before getting my turtlebeach headset. I used the headphone jack on a Samsung TV with a bluetooth adaptor to send audio wirelessly to a basic headset. Can't remember if the TV also outputted sound at the same time, but then why would you care if you have headphones working?

Comment: Is there a receiver in the mix or something? Do you get sound from any other source to the headphones? No reason I can think of this shouldn't work.

Comment: That last sentence ("I heard before that a TV cannot do both input from HDMI and output -said input- at the same time.") makes no sense.  If this were technically true, a TV could only "read" in sound via HDMI, and not output it at all (e.g. not even to the TV's speakers).  If the TV can output the sound to it's speakers, it should technically be possible to output via the headphones, and I'm surprised that's not the default behavior for your particular TV.  Are you getting sound from the PS3 on your TV?  What happens when you plug in the headphones?  No sound on the TV?  Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Sony Bravia TV has an "Audio Out". This is a pair of RCA pins on the back of the TV. The Audio Out routes sound from currently active input. The settings menu should have settings to mute the TV speakers as well as set if the volume settings (from remote) affect the audio out.

I don't believe there is an easy way to mute TV speakers alone, so every time you connect the headphones you might have to go through the settings menu to have sound come from the headphones alone.

Comment: My Samsung TV has similar functionality. I have an AppleTV connected via HDMI, I also have a 3.5 mm cable connected to the TV that outputs sound to a receiver. In order to hear sound from the receiver I have to navigate the TV settings to enable it. This functionality is probably similar but different on every television especially between makes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried buying a pair of turtle beaches? It would allow you to use the sound from the PS3 instead of the tv.

Other option is to swing by your local radioshack and buy a RCA to headphone jack cable that would allow you to use the TV out and control the output that way.